# Dynamically Fill your PDF Forms using silverlight

Tags: pdf, silverlight-4.0, itext

```
string pdfTemplate = @"Trust App form.pdf";
            string newFile = @"Trust App form Completed.pdf";

            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(
                        newFile, FileMode.Create));
            AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

            pdfFormFields.SetField("trust.trustee.entityname.line1", "Gulistan-e-Jauhar Karachi");
            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
            pdfStamper.Close();
```

I am able to fill pdf forms using Itext sharp pdf.

But problem is this pdf is for .net. **I WANT TO USE IT IN SILVERLIGHT**.
Is there any alternative? for filling pdf form in silverlight... what i think itext sharp give silverpdf (http://silverpdf.codeplex.com/) but there is `pdfstamper` and `acrofields` classes in silverpdf.

Answer (score 1):

SilverPDF looks to be inspired/based-on iTextSharp and PDFSharp, but it doesn't use an identical class layout by any means.

I just poked around in their code a bit (they have no docs that I could find), and it looks like you need to get the field's `PdfAcroField` object from the `PdfAcroForm`, which you get from a `PdfDocument`, which in turn you get from `PdfReader.open(...)`.

When the docs aren't good enough, check the code if at all possible.